# How to enable vertical scroll bar while debugging responsive design on mobile?

Tags: css, google-chrome-devtools

Mac + Chrome 101 build

In below case, how can I enable vertical scroll bar without which I can't view bottom of mobile screen.

Is this bug or I am missing some setting ?

[image]

Comment: You can scroll, drag from bottom to top, click in the page to get the focus and use up and down keys. Because there are no scrollbar in mobile I don't think you can show one like desktop

Comment: strangely in FF I can see scrollbar which helps to view bottom of mobile screen.

Comment: Do you mean you can't scroll within the viewport of the "emulated" device, or you can't scroll the screen around it to see the entirety of the device?

Comment: I can't scroll "the screen" around it to see the entirety of the device.